# Can 'though' be used at the start of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to start a sentence with 'though'?

For example:

> Though irreducibly simple in its design, this equation underpins much of the discussion surrounding ECS; thus, it serves a significant purpose in understanding and subsequently constraining ECS to within reasonable bounds.

First of all, is this sentence grammatical?

Secondly, is 'though' used correctly?

Comment: Though I don't understand how an equation can be "irreducibly simple in its design", I see nothing syntactically wrong in your sentence.

Comment: Yes -  it's grammatically okay, though I'd replace the rather clumsy ";thus, it serves" by the simpler "thus serving". The expression "Though irreducibly simple in its design" is an adjunct of concession.

Comment: It's pretty good, better if you get Stoned and Billed.

Comment: Though unlikely, I think it might be possible.

Comment: I think you might be concerned about a different kind of sentence that starts with *though*, one that sounds like an afterthought.  Those sentences aren't grammatical enough for a formal piece of writing.  However, your sentence isn't like that, and it's fine.

Comment: Though it might not seem so, though is used all the time at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: What makes you think this sentence isn't grammatical?

Comment: Yes. You get the same meaning if you replace the starting *though* with *although it is*.